# Avoiding defensive copies in readonly record structs

Tags: c#, struct, properties, field, defensive-copy

Let's say we have following readonly record struct definition

```cs
public readonly record struct S(int A, int B)
{
   
}
```

Accessing `A` and `B` will result in a defensive copy since in a record the positional parameters will be auto-implemented as properties.

We could avoid it by modifying the definition like this

```cs
public readonly record struct S(int A, int B)
{
   public readonly int A = A;
   public readonly int B = B;
}
```

In this case `A` and `B` are fields, hence no side effects on access, hence no defensive copies. From my tests and understanding in both definitions the compiler synthesizes the same record specific code(Equality, HashCode generation, etc...).

I am wondering if there is a better way to avoid defensive copies with records. Definition of all the readonly fields can be cumbersome and potentially error prone. Is there any C# Syntax to achieve what I am aiming to do here or are the readonly fields the best I can do?

Also if my understanding of defensive copies and record code synthesis in this example is wrong please explain what I didn't get right.

Edit:

The Measurement:

```cs
const int SIZE = 10000;

var sw = new Stopwatch();
A[] aArray = new A[SIZE];
M[] mArray = new M[SIZE];
for(int repeat = 0; repeat < SIZE; repeat++) aArray[repeat] = new A(new(new(new(new(new(new(new(new(new(new(new(Random.Shared.Next()))))))))))));
for(int repeat = 0; repeat < SIZE; repeat++) mArray[repeat] = new M(new(Random.Shared.Next()));
int i = 0;
sw.Start();
for(int repeat = 0; repeat < SIZE; repeat++) i =+ aArray[repeat].B.C.D.E.F.G.H.I.J.K.L.I;
sw.Stop();
System.Console.WriteLine(i);
System.Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
sw.Reset();
sw.Start();
for(int repeat = 0; repeat < SIZE; repeat++) i =+ mArray[repeat].N.I;
sw.Stop();
System.Console.WriteLine(i);
System.Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

readonly record struct A(B B){public readonly B B = B;}
readonly record struct B(C C){public readonly C C = C;}
readonly record struct C(D D){public readonly D D = D;}
readonly record struct D(E E){public readonly E E = E;}
readonly record struct E(F F){public readonly F F = F;}
readonly record struct F(G G){public readonly G G = G;}
readonly record struct G(H H){public readonly H H = H;}
readonly record struct H(I I){public readonly I I = I;}
readonly record struct I(J J){public readonly J J = J;}
readonly record struct J(K K){public readonly K K = K;}
readonly record struct K(L L){public readonly L L = L;}
readonly record struct L(int I){public readonly int I = I;}
readonly record struct M(N N){public readonly N N = N;}
readonly record struct N(int I){public readonly int I = I;}

readonly record struct A(B B){}
readonly record struct B(C C){}
readonly record struct C(D D){}
readonly record struct D(E E){}
readonly record struct E(F F){}
readonly record struct F(G G){}
readonly record struct G(H H){}
readonly record struct H(I I){}
readonly record struct I(J J){}
readonly record struct J(K K){}
readonly record struct K(L L){}
readonly record struct L(int I){}
readonly record struct M(N N){}
readonly record struct N(int I){}
```

I don't know what happened but know I redid the measurement and got similar values in both cases.

To run it just comment out the other definitions. The reason why I nested so many structs in structs is that I wanted to make sure that access of a field of a struct in a field of another struct doesn't make a copy as well.

I am sorry for the confusion. Apparently I did something wrong the first time around. There should not be any defensive copies in both cases.

Comment: What makes you think there will be a defensive copy? "properties" isn't enough - the entire type is marked `[IsReadOnly]`, which usually *prevents* defensive copies; even if the record isn't marked `readonly`, the *individual properties* are marked `[IsReadOnly]`, as is `ToString` etc

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre] where it shows the defensive copies.

Comment: @MarcGravell I measured. With fields the access was faster. I would think this is due to defensive copies. Also a property getter could have side effects which would violate the readonly modifier on a struct. From my research the compiler makes defensive copies to mitigate it.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, a record is just syntactic sugar over a class or struct. And the main case I'm aware of when defensive copies are made is when using the `in` parameter modifier with a mutable struct.

Comment: please post your measure; that's something we can talk about - the JIT will usually elide pass-thru properties, and defensive copies: isn't a thing here. Let's not guess: please show your actual scenario

Comment: How did you do your measurements? It is fairly easy make mistakes when measuring and measure the incorrect thing.

Comment: _"I measured."_ - please share the code **how** you have measured this and the measurement results. _"I would think this is due to defensive copies."_ - don't guess, check the generated IL code and compiled assembly one. _"Also a property getter could have side effects"_ - but in this case it does not since it is compiler generated.

Comment: I didn't new the getter of a property can be marked Readonly via an attribute and that it is done by the compiler. In that case it makes sense that there are no defensive copies.

Comment: With the edit: there *may* be copies in this scenario - but they're not *defensive* copies - they're simply semantic copies, meaning: a standard property getter means "copy out the value" (which the JIT may or may not elide); if you are dealing with large nested structs, there *may be* a case for accessible readonly fields, specifically to avoid these semantic copies; note that in the case of classes, there's also a ref-return getter (`ref readonly SomeType Member {get;}`), but that is less useful in the case of value-types (a struct can't ref-return relative to `this`, because of stack usage)

Comment: @MarcGravell What you are saying is that there may be copies here but only because the compiler sees no need to not just return a copy since the struct is small enough. If a struct would be larger the compiler might skip the copy because it would cost too much. Is that right? And about the ref return getter. Is this something that is also created automatically? It could be interesting for me if some of the structs might get to big.

Comment: @patvax no, I'm saying that the *meaning* of a standard property "get" is: "return the value on the top of the stack", which in the case of a field-backed property means: "copy the value of the field only to the top of the stack" - i.e. "ldarg0, ldfld, ret" ; if we get lucky, the JIT may see through that, and *remove* the copy operation and replace it with by-ref usage - but this isn't compiler-time operation; the compiler is obligated to perform the copy for a simple get

Comment: @patvax ref return getters are an advanced / niche thing, but don't quite apply in this case because a `struct` can't return a `ref` relative to `this`, but if the outer thing is a `class`, then: `class Foo { private SomeLargeStruct _inner; public ref readonly SomeLargeStruct Inner => ref _inner; }` - here `obj.Inner` is a *property* that returns by-ref ref-readonly access to the field

Comment: and because I suspect you're about to ask: the reason a `struct` can't return a `ref` relative to `this` is because that `struct` could be a transient on the top of the stack (not in a local or field), in which case `this` is about to evaporate, since member-access performs an implicit "pop" - so you'd be left with a reference to a transient memory position that has undefined contents

Comment: I wasn't about to ask because it was perfectly logical but thanks anyways ;)

Comment: Maybe of interest is [Sergey Tepliakov's ErrorProne.NET](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/avoiding-struct-and-readonly-reference-performance-pitfalls-with-errorprone-net/#:~:text=The%20compiler%20will%20never%20emit%20a%20defensive%20copy,category%20are%20non-readonly%20structs%20with%20no%20exposed%20fields.) NuGet package to analyse source code for unwanted defensive copies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no defensive copies here; readonly records are marked `[IsReadOnly]`, as are get-only properties - which tells the compiler enough that they *aren't needed*; you can see this in the IL, for example if we do:

```cs
using System;

void NoCopies(in S obj)
{   // no copies because the *type* is [IsReadOnly]
    Console.WriteLine(obj.A);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.B);
}

void AlsoHasNoCopies(in T obj)
{   // no copies because the *members* are [IsReadOnly]
    Console.WriteLine(obj.A);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.B);
}

void StillNoCopies(in LazyManual obj)
{   // no copies because the *members* are [IsReadOnly]
    Console.WriteLine(obj.A);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.B);
}


void DoesHaveCopies(in BasicManual obj)
{   // finally, we have defensive copies
    Console.WriteLine(obj.A);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.B);
}


public readonly record struct S(int A, int B)
{
   
}

public record struct T(int A, int B) // not marked readonly
{
   
}

public struct LazyManual
{
    public int A {get;} // auto-marked [IsReadOnly]
    public int B {get;}
}

public struct BasicManual
{
    private int _a, _b;
    public int A => _a; // not auto-marked [IsReadOnly]
    public int B => _b;
}
```

And compile/decompile this, we see:

```cs
[CompilerGenerated]
internal class Program
{
    private static void <Main>$(string[] args)
    {
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    internal static void <<Main>$>g__NoCopies|0_0([In][IsReadOnly] ref S obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.A);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.B);
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    internal static void <<Main>$>g__AlsoHasNoCopies|0_1([In][IsReadOnly] ref T obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.A);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.B);
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    internal static void <<Main>$>g__StillNoCopies|0_2([In][IsReadOnly] ref LazyManual obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.A);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.B);
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    internal static void <<Main>$>g__DoesHaveCopies|0_3([In][IsReadOnly] ref BasicManual obj)
    {
        BasicManual basicManual = obj;
        Console.WriteLine(basicManual.A);
        basicManual = obj;
        Console.WriteLine(basicManual.B);
    }
}
```

Only the last option of a manually implemented type that is *not* `readonly` and uses manual properties: has defensive copies.

---

For full context, we have:

```cs
[IsReadOnly]
public struct S : IEquatable<S>
{ ... }

public struct T : IEquatable<T>
{
    // ...
    public int A
    {
        [IsReadOnly]
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <A>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            <A>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }

    public int B
    {
        [IsReadOnly]
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <B>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            <B>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }
}

public struct LazyManual
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private readonly int <A>k__BackingField;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private readonly int <B>k__BackingField;

    public int A
    {
        [IsReadOnly]
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <A>k__BackingField;
        }
    }

    public int B
    {
        [IsReadOnly]
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <B>k__BackingField;
        }
    }
}

public struct BasicManual
{
    private int _a;

    private int _b;

    public int A
    {
        get
        {
            return _a;
        }
    }

    public int B
    {
        get
        {
            return _b;
        }
    }
}
```